# What's the first movie to use a prop to destroy/control an entire world?

Tags: first-appearance, props

1. Infinity stones in Avengers series
2. Mother Boxes in Justice league series
3. Aries prototype in F9: The Fast Saga
4. Project Starfish | The Suicide Squad (2021)

What's the first movie to use a prop to destroy/control an entire world?

Comment: To say nothing of the Illudium Q-36 Explosive Space Modulator.

Comment: If you don't like cartoons, The Day the Earth Stood Still (1951) has a robot that can destroy the Earth. I doubt it's the first such thing though.

Comment: Bonus points if the object is beautiful, shiny, jolly, and/or candy-like.

Comment: I think "MacGuffin" would be a better term than "prop". "Prop" refers to the physical object used in the real world by the filmmakers to represent an in-universe object.

Comment: Are you asking for a "prop which could control/destroy the word but was not used to so" or for a "prop which was used to destroy the world"?

Comment: @Nathaniel I would argue that Gort is a character. not a prop.

Comment: Does the planet Mongo count? (1936)

Comment: Nowhere near old enough (though still much older than all your examples), but does e.g. the Death Star count as a prop?  No Earth involved, but it is a planet destroyer.

Comment: Honorable mention to _[The Centauri Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centauri_Device)_  (1974).

Comment: What do you mean by "control" the entire world? The examples you gave don't seem to clearly apply.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Some of the examples in your question are technically not "props", so I will answer what I think you're *really* trying to ask, rather than following the exact wording of the question.

In [KoKo's Earth Control](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0136320/) from 1928, the main characters find a "Control of Earth" booth. There are levers to control the entire world (weather, seasons and day/night cycle) or destroy it. Below, you can see Fitz the Dog inspecting the lever that destroys the world.

[image: Fitz and the lever]

[image: Warning label]

You can watch KoKo's Earth Control on YouTube (**Warning: Flashing lights!**)

Comment: technically not a "prop" not portable, not a physical representation.

Comment: @Jasen It's a prop.

Comment: @Jasen Some of the examples listed in the original question are not physical representations of portable objects. I answered my best interpretation of what he was *really* trying to ask, not just a literal reading of the title.

Answer (score 4):

[The Mouse That Roared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse_That_Roared_(film)) 1959

"...Tully and Will stumble across Dr. Alfred Kokintz (David Kossoff), whose invention of the Q Bomb – capable of destroying an entire continent – has prompted the defence drills. He has built a football-sized prototype of the unstable bomb, which Tully takes possession of."

Comment: A continent isn't a world.

Comment: @RonJohn: The book makes it clear that the initial explosion of the quadium bomb would destroy a continent, give or take. But it would also have further side-effects, e.g. IIRC, a cloud of gas that would waft across the planet, killing everything in its wake. It was a doomsday device without question; no one wanted it to go off because it would mean the end of human life on Earth in short order. I can't say if the movie specifically covered that "extra helping of doom" though.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of the Death Star when reading "destroy an entire world".